# ggplot: grouped bar plot with column group ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
benchmark <- data.frame(
  num_element = c(10000, 40000, 70000, 100000, 130000),
  a = c(4.4363, 70.913, 215.83, 440.84, 740.84),
  b = c(5.6356, 26.254, 48.570, 71.882, 95.455),
  c = c(5.6356, 26.254, 48.570, 71.882, 95.455))
```

I want a grouped bar plot where all `a, b, c` value of the same `num_element` are together. This is how I plot it:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(reshape2)

data.m <- melt(benchmark, id.vars='num_element')

ggplot(data.m, aes(num_element, value))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
           width = 0.4, 
           position = position_dodge(width=0.5), 
           stat="identity")+  
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

But the graph looks like this:

[image]

Attempts:

I convert the `num_element` to all strings:

```
num_element = c('10000', '40000', '70000', '100000', '130000')
```

and got this plot:

[image]

How do I arrange the x-axis in increasing order? Is there a way to do it without converting `num_element` to String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `num_element` column into a factor:

```r
ggplot(data.m, aes(factor(num_element, ordered = TRUE), value))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), 
           width = 0.4, 
           position = position_dodge(width=0.5), 
           stat="identity")+  
  theme(legend.position="top", 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('10000', '40000', '70000', '100000', '130000'))
  # scale_x_discrete to write out all digits
```

[image]

Comment: you can use `scale_x_discrete` to replace `1e+05` by `100000`

Comment: hadn't spotted that at first, good fix